# Student of the Year program using structure

Tags: c, string, pointers, structure

My first problem is that I have problem to make that for loop and implement it into the code and somehow finish my program.

My second problem is compiler showing problem in this: `memset(database,0,SIZE*sizeof(struct student));` type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'

And at the end of program i have problem with `memcpy(database.name,name,size_of_name);` member reference base type 'struct student [100]' is not a structure or union

There are my structure and functions:

```
 #define SIZE 100

struct student {
char name[SIZE];
int votes;
};

struct student database[SIZE];
memset(database,0,SIZE*sizeof(struct student));
int size = 0;

int find_student(struct student* students,int size, const char* name){
    // for loop,which take all entries in database 
    // if it find same name, then reutrn his index 
    //otherwise reuturn -1;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<SIZE;i++){
        // how to make that loop
    }
     return -1;
}

int compare(const void* p1, const void* p2){
    struct student* s1 = (struct student*)p1;
    struct student* s2 = (struct student*)p2;
    // s1->votes 
    // s1->name 
    return 0;
}
```

And there is my code what I already did( sorry for my grammar):

```
char line[SIZE];
memset(line,0,SIZE);
char* r = fgets(line,SIZE,stdin);
if (r == NULL){
    printf("End of input");
    return (-1);
}
char* end = NULL;
int value = strtol(line,&end,10);
if (value == 0){
    printf("Convertion was not sucessful");
    return (-1);
}

// helping array
char name[SIZE];
// set on zero
memset(name,0,SIZE);
// get begining of a name = one position after space
char* beginning_name = end + 1;
// Size of name is number of signs to end of string
// minus end of line
int size_of_name = strlen(beginning_name) - 1;
if (size_of_name > 0){
    // copy
    memcpy(name,beginning_name,size_of_name);
    // At the end is saved string with name 
    // without end of line and with zero at the end
}
else {
    // failed to read a name
    printf("Failed to read a name");
    return (-1);
}

int id = find_student(database,size,name);
if (id< 0){
    // copy it to last place in array 
    memcpy(database.name,name,size_of_name);
    // increase number of entries 
    size+=1;
}
else {
    // there I need add to votes,something like votes++;

}


}
```

Sorry for formating but I am new at stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi @Gengar - welcome to stack overflow.  So it's not really clear what you are trying to do, and especially what you tried that didn't work - it just looks like a whole heap of random (and some bad) things - not an attempt at doing what is needed - you probably also don't need to be memsetting structures if you are getting the data from somewhere)..  Compiler errors - normally they are a clue as to what's wrong...

Comment: @MrR   I need for loop when i find same name,it returns his index.

Comment: Well how do you think you'd write it @Gengar?  the "for" steps over each index, so you need to find each of the elements in your structure, then use one of the string compare functions for C then use that to decide what to do next ...  Hint either a `break` or a `return` is required when the condition is met.

Comment: that's getting closer - you just need to refere to the correct element.  In find_student you'll be comparing `name` with `students[i].name` ...